# Query string (URL) lead to 403

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

Please help me on this.Already tried disable mode_security module through .htaccess no use.

> **PHP Version 5.6.30**

Apache redirect the request to 403 page if pass parameter below.

**&test[object_type]=0**

The name (**object_type**) leads to 403 page.

*`eg:http://www.cudec.com.my/?test[object_type]=0 ✖ NOT WORKING LEADS TO 403`*

*`eg:http://www.cudec.com.my/?test[object_types]=0 ✓ WORKING`*

Answer (score 0):

Will update this post to a full answer as soon as I got more information to work with ;)

---

I tried to call the 403-URL:

```
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

You ensured that ModSecurity is the one replying with 403? **Looks more like the folder permissions are insufficient.**

Check if your DocumentRoot is at least readable for users (an 'r' at the last triple or 4 in the last byte).

If it's really ModSecurity, have a look into /var/log/apache2/modsecurity_audit.log and you should see which rule (by ID) is the one throwing 403 and also the reason (Error-Msg in the rule) why.

Does http://www.cudec.com.my/?test[object_types]=0 return the expected result?

The parameter doesn't seem to be interpretated when using &test[object_type] instead of &test[object_types] and the target ressource / seems to have insufficient rights, same for the error-pages...

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply.i already check with permission for all the folder its seems good. My concern is the page is working without passing the parameter, so the folder permission is correct.The problem occurs only when i pass that particular parameter with word **object_type** all other parameters are working.

Comment: But when I receive a 403 while Apache is trying to handle the error...htdocs/error or whereever your errorpages are (myb in default path /usr/share/apache2/error/) there are definitely insufficient permissions present ;)  Additionally your object_type call seems to produce a problem, eventually related to rewrites you defined?! Are there any rewrites, redirects, proxypass etc. in play?